# updation issue during with ajax method

Tags: laravel

i am trying to update my record with ajax and i don't know here i am doing wrong the code with my ajax:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $('.edit_tag_button').click(function(){


        var id = $(this).parent().find('.tag_id').val();

        var formData = {
            'tag_type'       : $('#tag_type').val(),
            'quantity'  : $('#quantity').val(),
            'number'       : $('#number').val(),
            'active'  : $('#active').val(),
            'issued'     : $('#issued').val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{url('')}}/update/tagslist/"+id,// Url to which the request is send
            type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
            data: formData, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
            success: function(data) {

                swal("Success!", "Great Job!! Your data has been updated","success");

                location.reload();
            },
            error: function () {
                swal("Error", "Look like We got some problem. Can you please refresh the page and try again" , "error");
            }

        });
    });
});
```

and my controller code is:

public function updateTags(Request $request,$id)

```
{
    $plan = Tags::where('id',$id);

    $plan->update($request->all());
}
```

it says your values updated successfully but it does update my values any help plz

Comment: Can u provide `$request` listing and check for `$fillable` array in your `Tags` model

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel POST method required CSRF protection.

Make sure to add meta with csrf token content

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And share it to ajax setup.

```
$.ajaxSetup({headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')}});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for response but it does not working its shows me undefined id error when i check it from the console? any idea why its showing?

Comment: Can you share your laravel.log file?